# Large wait time after concurrent.futures closes

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I have a list of URLs which I am trying to get JSON data from. I am going through a list of 10,000s items so speed is key for me. This took forever in serial processing so I opted for using sessions. I have not used it before, but I have been able to produce something that is fast enough.

```
ar_list=['https//:www.foo.com',...,'https//:www.foo2.com']
adapter = HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=workers_num, pool_maxsize=workers_num)
data_list = []
with sessions.FuturesSession(max_workers=workers_num) as session:
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)  
    futures = []
    for idx, ar_url in enumerate(ar_list):
        resp = session.get(ar_url,headers=headers)
        futures.append(resp)
    end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_delta=end_time-start_time
```

This works nicely and runs a query within about 70us (with 10,000 queries).
I unfortunately have a problem getting the data.
`futures.append(resp)` gives me a Future object, and I need to run `.result().json()` on this to actually get usable information out. However when I add these, I get extremely slow operation speeds at about 0.4s per query (much slower than 70us!)

I have tried running the FutureSession quickly (as the code shows above), and then performing actions on the futures list later using:

1. for loop
2. list comprehension: `[item.result().json() for item in as_completed(futures)]`
3. lambda list operation: `list(map(lambda i: func(futures, i), range(0, len(futures))))`
4. finally trying another session to perform the operation:

```
data=[]
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as e:
    fut = [e.submit(func, i) for i in futures]
    for idx,r in enumerate(concurrent.futures.as_completed(fut)):
        print(str(idx))
        data.append(r.result())
```

Now this ThreadPoolExecutor works really well also, performing the task around 70us or so.
However, I am measuring at the start and end of `with` and notice that there is a large delay between these two `with` structures. It looks like this all together:

```
with sessions.FuturesSession(max_workers=workers_num) as session:
    #some fast operations here

"""
A VERY LARGE DELAY (about 60 seconds)
"""
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as e:
    #some fast operations here
```

Is there some cleanup of all of the sessions I create between the two `with` conditions that take a long time to resolve? I can see that there must be a better way of doing this than two sessions processes to just get some json data formatted correctly, but I can't seem to find the faster way.

Comment: The reason why you think that everything below with sessions.FuturesSession(max_workers=workers_num) as session: is fast is that it doesn't yet perform any/all HTTP requests. It only creates Futures that will eventually perform those requests. So the 70us are just creation time of get requests not the real execution.

Comment: I see what your saying, buy PyCharm debugger shows me something else. If I breakpoint at `futures.append(resp)` (in the first Futures), I already have a response and running `futures[0].result().json()` gives me what I want already. Does this happen because I am debugging and giving a lot of time for the Futures to run?

Comment: I have looked into this further, and it seems at the end of the `with` loop, sessions tries to close all the connections using `FuturesSession.close`
`def close(self):
        super(FuturesSession, self).close()
        if self._owned_executor:
            self.executor.shutdown()
`
This process is very slow and I believe if I could speed it up or avoid it, I might get some progress, but I have not come further than that

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research regarding this, I have discovered the big wait time that I experience is the `as_completed` call. As @Simon says, the large wait time is simply me waiting for the responses. If I remove `as_completed` it becomes as fast as ever, but of course the responses are garbage or `None`.

I am looking into avoiding the use of `as_completed` with a callback to avoid the need to wait for `as_completed` to occur on the futures, and just get them from a completed list. Hopefully I return soon with a "work around"

Comment: Have you tried using `ProcessPoolExecutor`  which uses process-based concurrency instead of threads?

Comment: I tried both. I even tried a nested ProcessPool inside a ThreadPool. Both were very slow. I am currently playing around with some async processes to see if I can speed it up

Comment: If you didn't gain from threads/processes, I doubt you will from an async approach. Can you show the definition of `func`? Your workload should be I/O bound if you're mostly fetching JSON files from HTTP. So something seems off :) FWIW this repo is a demo of pretty much what you're trying to do: https://github.com/kokke/concurrency-demo-py/